# Finding the probability that a word is correctly received

Tags: coding-theory

Let $C=\{000,111,222,333,444\}$

The question is to find the probability $p_c$ of a word being  correctly received if each symbol has the probability $t$ of being incorrectly received and each wrong symbol is equally likely.

The solution is $p_c=(1-t)^3+12 \times \frac{t}{4} (1-t)^2$

I understand the reasoning and understand where this expression comes from except for the dividing by $4$ term.

Some background behind the solution:
If $000$ is sent then the received words decoded as $000$ are

$000$ for which there is one of this.

$i00$ for $i \neq 0$ and there are four of these because $i$ could be replaced by $1,2,3$ or $4$

$0i0$ for $i \neq 0$ and there are four of these because $i$ could be replaced by $1,2,3$ or $4$

$0i0$ for $i \neq 0 $ and there are four of these because $i$ could be replaced by $1,2,3$ or $4$

So the $12$ in our solution comes from doing $3 \times 4$.

The formula used: P(i errors in specified positions)$=t^i (1-t)^{n-1}$

where $n$ is length of the code and $i$ is the number of errors so in our case it is $1$ barring when we are looking at the $000$ word as here there are no errors so $i=0$.

So the solution is $p_c=1^0 \times (1-t)^{3-0} + 4 \times t^1(1-t)^{3-2} + 4 \times t^1 (1-t)^{3-2} + 4 \times t^1(1-t)^{3-2}$

Which simplifies down to  $p_c=(1-t)^3+12 \times t (1-t)^2$

> Why do we divide $t$ by $4$?

Comment: What does it mean for a word to be " wrongly correctly received"?

Comment: Assuming that this refers to the word being received such that the intended word can be reconstructed from the unique letter in the majority, I don't see where the $12$ comes from -- the result is correct, but it's not clear to me why they write $\frac{12}4$ instead of $3$.

Comment: Can you clarify?  If, say, I hear the word $XYX$ do i conclude that the sender was aiming for $XXX$?

Comment: @joriki I have corrected the error

Comment: @lulu I have added more information to the post.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. The probability of a word being correctly received is $(1-t)^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're counting each letter as a separate event but then multiplying by the probability $t$ for any of them to occur. You should either count the event of receiving some wrong letter as a whole, and multiply by its probability $t$, or, if you want to treat the letters as separate events, you need to multiply by their individual probability, which is $\frac t4$. In either case, you end up with $3t$.